# How can i get a section background image below a navbar?

Tags: html, css

I want to put my first section just with a background image and a logo on center, but with my navbar being translucid, i would like to put that background image from the section below the navbar [thats how it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtDFz.png) and [this is what im looking after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE1c2.png), can anyone help me with this problem please? I tried a lot of things with position: relative or absolute and i couldn't get it, only got navbar below the background

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}

.interface {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}


/* Header */

header {
  padding: 40px 4%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.623);
  position: relative;
}

header>.interface {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

header a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: .2s;
}

header a:hover {
  color: #68b04d;
  transform: scale(1.10);
}

header nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

header nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 40px;
}

header nav .menu-desktop {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* LOGO SITE */

section.logo-site {
  padding: 170px;
  background-image: url(images/arte.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

section.logo-site img {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="interface">
    <nav class="menu-desktop">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Placeholder</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
  <!-- Interface -->
</header>

<main>
  <section class="logo-site">
    <div class="interface">
      <img src="images/logo.png">
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Sessão logo -->
</main>
```

Comment: You could take the header out of the flow by using position: absolute and z-index to keep it above, then the main element will automatically be positioned at the top edge, adjust its z-index as well. Another possible solution is to use CSS grid to position both the header and the main in the same cell, and use z-index to control what comes up top. You need to be aware of what you're doing and test all screen sizes so you don't end up with content being cut off.

Comment: Have you declared `position:relative` on any parent-element? Only then `position:absolute` works. And the translucid effect is `blur()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your background image won't show even with an rgba color. the opacity won't be able to show below it the background-image. You might need to add a div with image in it as position fixed and set a z-index with blur()as suggested by @deEr

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
  
  body {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
.background{
    position: fixed;
    filter: blur(3px);
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

  .interface {
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  .flex {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  
  /* Header */
  
  header {
    padding: 40px 4%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rgba(187, 55, 55, 0.355);
    position: relative;
  }
  
  header>.interface {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  header a {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: .2s;
  }
  
  header a:hover {
    color: #68b04d;
    transform: scale(1.10);
  }
  
  header nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  
  header nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 40px;
  }
  
  header nav .menu-desktop {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  
  /* LOGO SITE */
  
  section.logo-site {
    padding: 170px;
    /* background-image: url(image/image1.jpg); */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
  }
  
  section.logo-site img {
    width: 500px;
  }
```

```html
<header>
<div class="interface">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="background" alt="">
    </div>
    <nav class="menu-desktop">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Placeholder</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
  <!-- Interface -->
</header>

<main>
  <section class="logo-site">
    <div class="interface">
      <img src="images/logo.png">
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem repudiandae atque quo 
        numquam eaque eveniet, quasi cum quos iusto in! Illum ratione, quo nulla sapiente eum sit saepe! 
        Assumenda ut incidunt iste. Unde ex nisi vel quidem ut, adipisci provident inventore voluptate doloribus 
        saepe sunt blanditiis animi tenetur est eveniet, repudiandae sapiente officiis. Ipsam aut accusamus suscipit 
        quos porro animi numquam corporis minus magni odio impedit harum aliquam dolorum alias qui, obcaecati iure nisi reprehenderit commodi eos omnis, laborum a fuga! Amet quasi pariatur recusandae ipsa officiis assumenda modi, aperiam delectus fugiat dolor accusantium ipsum fugit sapiente aut necessitatibus natus sed id accusamus ut culpa, est consectetur corporis doloremque odio. Harum molestias fugit fuga voluptatibus rem delectus vitae aliquid et ad voluptatem ut praesentium natus assumenda eius eligendi maiores facere, necessitatibus ipsa minima excepturi vel dicta. Blanditiis sint dolorem corporis consequatur earum eos nam nulla vero harum nisi quam ipsa, placeat amet, repellat sed sapiente cum corrupti in voluptates ea quia nobis. Quidem dolore blanditiis quae molestias doloribus et vero saepe porro. Doloribus animi maiores ab odio voluptatem iste provident veritatis numquam magni sint aperiam dignissimos repellat quam, ipsam culpa aliquam illum, ad aut! Ducimus blanditiis voluptas excepturi accusamus velit aliquid, debitis quibusdam! Vero voluptatem maxime eligendi ratione labore soluta quidem error, possimus corporis debitis assumenda asperiores earum. Eveniet voluptatem excepturi nisi, praesentium saepe odio enim accusamus quis corrupti rerum doloremque. Placeat sit expedita sapiente quaerat perspiciatis, dolores quasi asperiores excepturi, consequuntur nobis doloremque repellendus quo est. Voluptate similique at deleniti vero ipsa, rem ullam esse enim id expedita fugit, a inventore veniam illo aliquid. Ullam necessitatibus deleniti consequatur porro modi eum adipisci dolor, fugit atque nulla voluptatum, temporibus id animi praesentium doloremque placeat odit! Rem quisquam dolorem iste quia, officia nulla dignissimos expedita incidunt labore amet ipsa pariatur, ullam molestiae, excepturi numquam perferendis minima? Earum consequuntur adipisci, laboriosam labore delectus commodi quibusdam ducimus veniam quod exercitationem deserunt illo id atque illum ullam eligendi eaque distinctio in nesciunt repellat! Minima odio sed quidem neque asperiores vel suscipit maiores repudiandae illo deserunt, repellendus reprehenderit alias natus aperiam recusandae assumenda! Dignissimos earum ipsa dolorum alias omnis vero pariatur nam, distinctio minus explicabo! Et doloremque expedita itaque numquam magnam ratione corporis ex maiores deleniti vero sapiente eum nesciunt praesentium sit culpa nam, cumque deserunt. Iure tempora magnam hic? Omnis commodi cumque eveniet ullam temporibus consequuntur veniam quae impedit ex fuga. Nam aliquam vel, fugit adipisci cumque voluptatum repudiandae voluptas nostrum vero porro doloribus ab omnis fugiat tempora quaerat! Nobis dignissimos magni quos perferendis commodi tempore laboriosam cumque iusto, fugiat temporibus! Quibusdam dolorem possimus libero cupiditate. Commodi minima repellat 
        non atque aliquid accusamus reprehenderit, nostrum consequuntur rerum maxime obcaecati est delectus explicabo, architecto voluptatibus.
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Sessão logo -->
</main>
```